# Neo4j Cypher : existing match path exists but no match is returned if first node is equal to last node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a path like the one in the image shown

[image: path]

When I do this match query, there is no match returned, which is strange:

```
match (a:A)--(b:B)--(c:C)--(d:D)--(c2:C)--(b2:B)--(a2:A)
where a.id = a2.id and b.id = b2.id
return count(d)
```

This one is giving no match too:

```
match (a:A)--(b:B)
with a,b 
match (a)--(b)--(c:C)--(d:D)--(c2:C)--(b)--(a)
return count(d)
```

But this one is giving the paths, if `C` type nodes have the property `B_id` which is the ID of their node `B` type attached to them:

```
match (c:C)--(d:D)--(c2:C)
where c.B_id = c2.B_id
return count(d)
```

This seems strange to me.
Any ideas on why those matches are not working?
Which would be the query to retrieve `count(d)`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your first query is almost correct, the only bit is that you're using a different alias for the same node `A` which would enforce that `a` and `a2` are different nodes in the graph, same for `b` and `b2`

Try this one

```
match (a:A)--(b:B)--(c:C)--(d:D)--(c2:C)--(b)--(a)
where a.id = a2.id and b.id = b2.id
return count(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your queries:

```
match (a:A)--(b:B)--(c:C)--(d:D)--(c2:C)--(b2:B)--(a2:A)
where a.id = a2.id and b.id = b2.id
return count(d)

match (a:A)--(b:B)
with a,b 
match (a)--(b)--(c:C)--(d:D)--(c2:C)--(b)--(a)
return count(d)
```

are not returning matches due to the last matches in your pattern `(c2:C)--(b2:B)--(a2:A)` and `(c2:C)--(b)--(a)`. The reason being there are only 1 `B` and 1 `A` nodes in your database. So, when these matches occur neo4j tries to find a new path between a and b, other than the one it has fetched from the beginning. Since, there is only one relationship between a and b, no path is found for this match. Hence, you see no matches. To fix it, you can simply remove `a` from the end, since it's redundant, like this:

```
match (a:A)--(b:B)--(c:C)--(d:D)--(c2:C)--(b)
return count(d)
```

The count returned above might seem incorrect due to the Cartesian product, for the exact count, use this:

```
match (a:A)--(b:B)--(c:C)--(d:D)--(c2:C)--(b)
return count(DISTINCT d)
```

**EDIT**

The graph you showed above, has only one `B` node, linked to `A`. The reason your path fails at the end is that (b)--(a) is already established, and no new path between b and a is there. I created multiple `B` nodes linked to `A` nodes, on an empty graph, using the queries:

```
MERGE (a:A{id: 1})
MERGE (b:B{id: 1})
MERGE (c:C{id: 1})
MERGE (c1:C{id: 2})
MERGE (c2:C{id: 3})
MERGE (d:D{id: 1})
MERGE (a)<-[:R]-(b)
MERGE (c)-[:R]->(b)
MERGE (c1)-[:R]->(b)
MERGE (c2)-[:R]->(b)
MERGE (c)-[:R]->(d)
MERGE (c1)-[:R]->(d)
MERGE (c2)-[:R]->(d)

// This is a separate query.
CREATE (b:B{id: 1})
WITH b
MATCH (c:C{id: 1})
MATCH (c1:C{id: 2})
MATCH (c2:C{id: 3})
MATCH (a:A{id: 1})
MERGE (b)-[:R]->(a)
MERGE (c)-[:R]->(b)
MERGE (c1)-[:R]->(b)
MERGE (c2)-[:R]->(b)
```

Now, the match is successful and a non-zero count is returned, using the query:

```
match (a:A)--(b:B)--(c:C)--(d:D)--(c2:C)--(b2:B)--(a2:A)
where a.id = a2.id and b.id = b2.id
return count(d)
```

Comment: That seems correct, thanks. I do not understand why the path is not counted, as it exists. It should account for them, because the whole path exists. Is it that it never fetches a sub-path that was fetched already? What if we do not know that (a)--(b) is unique?  
The problem with your answer is that in my data there are more than one b linked to the same a, so b and b2 could be different. How to account for that?

Comment: After the edit on the answer: Indeed, this is returning a count, but ignoring the ones that go a--b--c--d--c2--b--a , it seems to me. So the answer is correct in that sense, but the problem is not solved, because that query ignores cases where b = b2 and there is a unique a--b connection.  
If we want to know the count of d that exist between a and a2, including the case when a = a2, and the case where b = b2 , then how do we do it?

Comment: By looking for a path, in the `WHERE` clause, like this:

`match (a:A)--(b:B)--(c:C)--(d:D)--(c2:C)
where (c2)--(b)--(a)
return count(d)`

This returns the count even on the original graph. @miguelvazq